# How to prepend a list of arrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am baffled by the following example.
First, this works as expected:

```
# create a vector
x = "a" # a string, or an Integer, or a float
L = fill(x, 3)
# prepend something:
prepend!(L, x)
```

This doesn't:

```
# create a vector
x = rand(3,2) # an array
L = fill(x, 3)
# prepend something:
prepend!(L, x)
```

(The error is `` ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Float64 to an object of type Matrix{Float64} ``)

My questions are

1. Why?!? Why are vector of strings and vector of arrays treated differently?
2. How should I prepend an array in a list of arrays?

Comment: The first example doesn't "work as expected". You might want `prepend!(L, [x])` for both cases. In any case, filling a vector with arrays using the same memory is suspect (but it may be just for the example). Finally, the function you are looking for might be `pushfirst!`

Comment: `pushfirst!` and `prepend!` should naturally be slower than `push!`, and some algorithmic thinking might be used to avoid them in performance code.

Comment: Fair enough. You are right, it is the first example which is surprising.

Comment: I've checked the first example locally on 1.9.2 and it errors (just like the second example). If `L` is a `Vector{Any}` it might work, as a `String` is an iterable of `Char`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now (I should look at the code to be sure, but this is my guess): `prepend!` basically calls `collect` on the second argument. The first example works because `collect(3)[1]` gives `3`. So the lone integer `3` apparently behaves like a vector.

Answer (score 0):

To prepend a single element of type Array to a vector of Arrays, you can use `pushfirst!` as follows:

```
julia> L = [rand(2,2) for _ in 1:3]
3-element Vector{Matrix{Float64}}:
 [0.5419857375401973 0.2692820074666489; 0.703052676811784 0.5238472215690597]
 [0.10161344289382412 0.9843236824319113; 0.09766922162281089 0.38813184523829924]
 [0.6395337491963987 0.42876328271820074; 0.6725871327351192 0.12483693948740737]

julia> x = rand(2,2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.697848  0.13222
 0.110205  0.223819

julia> pushfirst!(L, x)
4-element Vector{Matrix{Float64}}:
 [0.6978484513001895 0.13221996502980904; 0.11020531088254903 0.2238189013944245]
 [0.5419857375401973 0.2692820074666489; 0.703052676811784 0.5238472215690597]
 [0.10161344289382412 0.9843236824319113; 0.09766922162281089 0.38813184523829924]
 [0.6395337491963987 0.42876328271820074; 0.6725871327351192 0.12483693948740737]
```

The same `pushfirst!` can be used to insert an element which is compatible with the `eltype` of the Vector to any Vector.

To insert several elements at once, `prepend!` can be used.

Welcome to Julia, Olivier. It was once the shiny new thing, and now it's just the shiny thing :).